# Cgs to Si with Force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, dimensional-analysis, units, si-units

So i just have a Problem with the transition from Cgs to SI. I want to Calculate the Force of the Plates of a Capacitor. The Formula is the following:(k=1,2,3 and Einstein Notation is used and T is the Maxwell Stress Tensor)
$$
F_k=\int_{}^{}T_{ik}df_k
$$
but what bothers me is, that in cgs the Unit for Force (F) is:
$$
[F_k]=dyn=\frac{g*cm}{s^2}
$$
but the units on the right side of the equation are:
$$
[T_{ik}]*[df_k]=Gs*cm^2=\sqrt{\frac{g}{cm*s^2}}*cm^2=\frac{\sqrt{g}*cm^{3/2}}{s}
$$
and well thats not the same and i just dont see the mistake.
Source for the Gs unit:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9F_(Einheit)

Comment: A dyne is $\frac{g \; cm}{s^2}$

Comment: thanks, but sadly they still arent the same ::(

Comment: Why do you think $T$ has units of Gauss? Surely if $T\sim B^2$ it has units of ${\rm Gauss}^2$?

Comment: ahh. youre right. thanks. forgot that during the calculation of the tensor